# Access Excel workbook from javascript

Tags: javascript, excel

Is there a way to access an Excel worksheet using javascript?

Comment: This made me laugh my ass off. If you could the pertinent question is: WHY WOULD YOU WANT TO?

Comment: The data I wanted to display is in an Excel worksheet in our intranet. As much as possible I don't want to setup a web application just to be able to display the content of the excel worksheet.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert excel to csv or json by using php and the show it in datatable using YUI Datatable or ExtJS data grid.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar (display Excel data in a web page without requiring a web server). After reviewing the options, I decided to export the data to XML and process it with Javascript. See [this page on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/XML/xml_examples.asp) (look for the "Parsing XML with JavaScript" section. This turned out to be much easier than mucking around with ActiveX components to access Excel spreadsheets directly.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Why is the data in an Excel worksheet?  I have no idea your application, but for whatever you are trying to do I would probably suggest putting the data into a database table somewhere.  Then your web site can pull from the database with ASP or PHP or your language of choice, and whatever you are doing with Excel right now could be done with Access.

Comment: How about user generated data that's then imported into a webapp. Excel is ubiquitous and is often far easier for users to use (especially when given a template) than anything else.

Comment: Part of the import step should involve converting it from XLS[X] to a format your website can use more readily. Read it into a database, convert it to CSV, anything like that.

Comment: Expecting your users to "read it into a database" is not reasonable.

Comment: @adewinter I don't expect the users to do that. I expect the server to do it. Let the users work on the data in whatever format they want. Just because the users are using XLS doesn't mean that's the format you should store on your website. Let them upload an XLS, then immediately import that into your database. This is similar to how you might edit a google docs spreadsheet locally right now.